# Figuring out key in hill cipher (chosen-plaintext attack)

Tags: keys, chosen-plaintext-attack, hill-cipher

I have been wondering what approach to take in order to figure out what key was used to encrypt a message using the hill cipher. 
I know it is possible to obtain it even if it were just a known-plaintext attack, so it should be fairly possible for a chosen-plaintext one. 
I'm trying to figure it out with just intuition, but since I know freq. analysis won't be of help, I don't know what else to try. I want to get my head around this, but could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure.  Assuming that you're using the encoding $A = 0$, $B = 1$, etc., just choose your plaintext messages to be the one-block strings:

$$
BA \dots A \\
AB \dots A \\
\vdots \\
AA \dots B
$$

The encryptions of these strings will then directly give you the columns of your key matrix.

Comment: Sorry, it seems like I misunderstood your answer. I thought I could just encrypt each letter in the plaintext at a time,  but it doesn't work since the key matrix is at least 2x2, right? Could you elaborate a bit more on what you mean by one-block strings?

Comment: @Emyr: See this [description of the Hill cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_cipher): for an n.n matrix, plaintext letters are grouped by vectors of n letters. Ilmari Karonen suggest to encipher the n distinct vectors of n letters with n-1 A and 1 B; the resulting ciphertext is n vectors of n letters, which form the n.n key matrix.

Answer (score 1):

An easier way to say what Ilmari Karonen [said](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/3886/73763) is: Choose the plaintext to be the identity matrix. Thus, when it is multiplied by the key, the resultant ciphertext will be the key it self.

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography. This is rather a comment. Also, the plaintext in the Hill cipher is not a Matrix, it is a [vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_cipher). Ofcource you can calculate an $n$ vector by the $n\times x$ key matrix.